# How to do something like document.getElementById().value in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have some code that includes a react form that has something like this in it :

```js
<input id="region"></input>
```

I have a function that is called from a button click and I want to get the value of the id "region".

I have seen that supposedly I can do something like this :

```js
let test : string = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById(region).value;
```

But I can verify 8 ways to Sunday that does not work. I get syntax errors saying a comma is missing if I try that.

So is there a way to do this? What am I missing? treat me like an idiot since I am only 48 hours into typescript.

Comment: Note that in React, as in Angular and others, you generally don't use the DOM to get values; you bind values to objects in state (see https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html).

Answer (score 7):

I assume you're using React due to the tag, and thus I assume the following code is in a tsx file.

```
let test : string = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById(region).value;
```

You cannot use arrow bracket casts in TSX files because TypeScript will assume you're trying to use a React Element. You must instead use the `as` form of casts:

```
let test : string = (document.getElementById(region) as HTMLInputElement).value;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add a couple of notes, because I cannot comment. While using TypeScript, and although all valid JS is valid TS as well, @Heretic Monkey is right the DOM is not generally used to manipulate the values.

Additionally, there are two mistakes in your TypeScript:

---`let test : string = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById(region).value;`---

Firstly, I believe you cannot initialize your variable and access the element's value at the same time. You ought to first assign your variable to the input element, and then use the variable to access its value. Example:

`let test : string = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById(region);`

`console.log(`*`test.value`*`);`

Secondly, the element's `id` should be quoted in both cases. When assigning the id inside the tag itself, and when trying to access it.

`let test : string = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById(`*`"region"`*`);`

A little late to this question, but if it is not solved and you're still struggling, give it a go. Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Typescript is a superset of Javascript. Every valid Javascript code is a valid Typescript code.

If what you are trying to do isn't working as intended, it is for another reason.

Comment: The syntax error only shows up if I enter that specific line of typescript in the code. If I take it out/comment it out, it works without error...

Comment: could you add some more context then ? because it is clearly not a typescript issue...

Comment: It is a TypeScript issue. OP omitted a crucial part of their code.

Comment: The lack of typing isn't consistent with the error he is getting.

Comment: However the lack of `"` around `region` in the argument is.

Comment: There is no issue with that, either. The problem is that OP is using angle bracket casts in a TSX file. He didn't have the cast in his original code but he updated his answer to show it.

Comment: So it was a React related issue, not a Typescript one.

Comment: And if it wasn't a React component, his code would have resulted in a wrong type error and not a missing comma one. Typescript doesn't render a Javascript statement invalid by itself.

Comment: I don't see how your comments are in pursuit of helping the OP, just defending your own answer. That's not what this site is about.

Comment: My comment are in the pursuit of helping OP understand where the error is lying. His problem isn't a lack of understanding of typescript. It lies in the tsx interpreting the valid `<>`  type coercion operator as an element. Which would never happen outside of the React ecosystem. You cannot write invalid Typescript code by writing Javascript code.

Answer (score -2):

you must use ref in react:
Then call it in your function.
Like this

```
private regioninput: HTMLInputElement;

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.regioninput = null;
    this.setregionInputRef = element => {
        this.stepInput = element;
    };
}
```

your element change :

```
   <input type="text" ref={this.setregionInputRef} />
```