# is there a way to do something similar to document.getelementbyid() in this situation

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am working on a project where i try to implement a search function. My first step is to make sure that all input is set to lower case to make SQL calls easier. However i have stumbled upon a problem that i am struggling to fix. I do not know how to do a document.getElementById('') in react typescript. I am quite new to these languages and have tried the solutions found here ([How to do something like document.getElementById().value in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57326731/how-to-do-something-like-document-getelementbyid-value-in-typescript)) but this does not seem to get the data stored in my element.

**So im wondering how can i get the input in the searchbar into the variable defaultText.**

here is the element that i want to grab

```
<Row><input type="search" id="form1" onChange={this.input} placeholder="Søk etter oppskrift.."/></Row>
```

here is the function which i attempt to set the input to lower case

```
  input(){
    const defaultText:string = (document.getElementById('form1') as HTMLInputElement).value;
    console.log (defaultText);
      // To convert Lower Case
      let lowerCaseText = defaultText.toLowerCase();
      console.log(lowerCaseText);
    
  }
```

The outcome from both 'console.log' is simply an empty row

Comment: You should use a `useState` to remember the value of the input. Set it using `value`. Then in you` onChange` function, set it to lower before calling the `set` function.

Comment: You cannot use `document.getElementById` in React. But you can easily read the value of a form by binding your state to the input field. Something like this: `<input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />` . See https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use native javascript selectors for this. You can just use the `onChange` method, first parameter will give you the ChangeEvent for the input change. You can get the value simply by `event.target.value` (assuming the parameter is taken as `event`).

Furthermore you can save this value to the state using `useState`.

See the changed code.

```
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");      

  function onChange(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>){
    const defaultText:string = event.target.value;
    // To convert Lower Case
    let lowerCaseText = defaultText.toLowerCase();
    
    // You can either save lowerCaseText or defaultText here
    setInputValue(defaultText):
    
  } 


 <Row><input type="search" id="form1" onChange={onChange} placeholder="Søk etter oppskrift.." value={inputValue}/></Row>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use state, it will be the best way to handle it, and it's "the React way"
See [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

Higher up in the component you will need to declare the initial value of your input:

```js
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState("");

// In typescript you can also do the following: 
// const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState<string>("");
```

Later on you will need to use the state, as well as manage when it is updated:

```js
<Row>
  <input
    type="search"
    id="form1"
    value={inputValue}
    onChange={(event) => {
      setInputValue(event.target.value)
    }}
    placeholder="Søk etter oppskrift.."
    />
</Row>
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74265996/is-there-a-way-to-do-something-similar-to-document-getelementbyid-in-this-situ#comment131116109_74265996) to an answer to give an example.

---

You should use an `useState` to remember the value of the input. Set it using value. Then in your `onChange` function, set it to lower before calling the set function.

Demo without typescript:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React; 

function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');

  const onInputValue = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value.toLowerCase())
  };

  return (
    <input type="search" value={value} id="form1" onChange={onInputValue} placeholder="Søk etter oppskrift.."/>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```